What is RTT connection and monitoring connection in atlas?
I am using this documentation to calculate the number of connections my service will have:
docs/manual/tutorial/connection-pool-performance-tuning
instances of the python application that connects to atlas.
After setting the configs maxPoolSize and minPoolSize to 1, using atlas connection logs I have identified each instances makes 3 connections, which is in line with what the documentation says.
However 2 of those connections (RTT and monitoring) are not used by me and I was wondering what they are, if they are necessary to establish and run a connection pool, and if not, is there a way to remove them?
Also, if there is a way to totally avoid connection pooling and have a standalone connection, I would be quite happy to explore that route if it means I won't have to handle 2 extra connections per instance.
PS: Cannot do anything reducing the number of instances, and cannot share resources across instances.
